# How to transform rows to column in a scala 2d array using scala api operations

Tags: arrays, scala, api, transform, scala-collections

I wanted to transform the rows to columns in a scala 2d array in the most effective way

### Input:

```
val arr1 = Array(
        Array(1, 10),
        Array(2, 20),
        Array(3, 30),
        Array(4, 40)
    )
```

### Output:

```
val arr2 = Array(
        Array(1, 2, 3, 4),
        Array(10, 20, 30, 40)
    )
```

similar to a matrix transpose.

Naive solution:

```
  val resArr = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()
  val columnSize = arr1.head.size
  val rowSize  = arr1.size
  for (i <- 0 until columnSize) {
      for (j <- 0 until rowSize) {
          resArr += arr1(j)(i)
      }
  }
  resArr
```

## Question

What I am looking for:
1. Is there any internal API in scala that I could use.
2. Can I use a flat map based on column vs row?
3. Is there an efficient way to do with this with less time complexity?

Looking for suggestion from scala experts.

Comment: [`transpose`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#transpose[B](implicitasArray:A=%3EArray[B]):Array[Array[B]]).

Answer (score 0):

`transpose` as @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez suggests.

```
scala> val arr1 = Array(
     |         Array(1, 10),
     |         Array(2, 20),
     |         Array(3, 30),
     |         Array(4, 40)
     |     )
arr1: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 10), Array(2, 20), Array(3, 30), Array(4, 40))

scala> arr1.transpose
res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Array(10, 20, 30, 40))
```